# OpenCart dynamic menu from database

Tags: php, html, menu, twig, opencart

I have a dynamic menu.php written in html/php, it sets the menu structure based on my database. I have an OpenCart site, and need the same menu at that site, but I only have twig files( header.twig ), and I can't put PHP into it, but I need the same menu with dynamic elements in that OpenCart site. Is it possible to switch from twig to PHP?

Comment: Vague explanation. Directly switch from twig to php not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to rewrite your logic in twig. You can also try PHP to twig converters like https://php2twig.com.

I am not sure if it will work directly.

Comment: no directly, directly does not work. There you can try to convert only from php to twig, but also with errors. After conversion  you must to check  and fix the errors.